# How to sort two vectors together in R?

Tags: r

I have two vectors:

```
vector1<- c(0.01,0.02,0.04,0.5,0.9,0.002,0.07,0.008)
 vector2<- c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
```

`vector2` shows the membership of each element of `vector 1` in specific set. I want to sort `vecotor1`, but `vector 2` also should be sorted w.r.t `vector 1`. how can  I impelemt it in R ?

expected output :

```
sort(vector1, decreasing=T)
[1] 0.900 0.500 0.070 0.040 0.020 0.010 0.008 0.002

>sorted_vector2:
 [1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: Why are you re-posting the same question a second time?

Comment: because you'r answer was wrong !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `order`, which returns the permutation used by `sort`:

```
vector2[order(vector1, decreasing=TRUE)]
[1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
```